# How to link multiple pages in GWT

Tags: gwt, onload

I am new to GWT and so my knowledge is restricted.

Right now I have created a simple Login page which will take my user to another page and then based on the choices that the user makes, it will direct it to the next page. I have created 3 individual pages but I have no clue how to link them. Can someone please help.

Answer (score 1):

In GWT typically you do not create separate pages - you create separate "views". They may look like pages to an end user, but in reality the entire app works in a single HTML "host" page.

You may want to look at the [Activities and Places](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html) design pattern. It takes care of navigation between different "places" within your app.

Comment: Isnt this the MVP architecture of GWTP. I am working on GWT. Isnt there any way I can work only with GWT and not include GWTP?

Comment: I use it in plain GWT all the time. I never used GWTP, so I cannot compare them, but Activities and Places is a good way to organize a pure GWT app with multiple "places"/view.

Comment: I always thought MVP was a feature of GWTP. Thanks a lot for the information. I will dive in and check if it works good.

Answer (score 0):

very simple example with a `DeckPanel`. It shows only the selected 'page' and hides the other ones

```
DeckPanel deckPanel = new DeckPanel();
deckPanel.add(page1);
deckPanel.add(page2);
deckPanel.add(page3);

deckPanel.showWidget(0);
//deckPanel.showWidget(1);
//deckPanel.showWidget(2);
```